# Showing this sequence of functions not equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

Consider the sequence of functions $\{Q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined in the proof of Rudin's theorem 7.26:

$$Q_n(x)=c_n(1-x^2)^n$$

where coefficient $c_n$ is choosen so that $\int_{-1}^1 Q_n(x)dx=1$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. I wish to show that $\{Q_n\}$ is not equicontinuous.

Here is my attempt:

Pick $\epsilon=\frac{c_1}{2}$. Let $\delta>0$. Choose $x=0$ and $y=\frac{\delta}{2}$. Since $Q_n\to0$ uniformly on $[-1,-\frac{\delta}{2}]\cup[\frac{\delta}{2},1]$, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $|f_N(x)|<\frac{c_1}{2}$ for any $x\in[-1,-\frac{\delta}{2}]\cup[\frac{\delta}{2},1]$. In particular, $f_N(y)<\frac{c_1}{2}$. Then, $|f_N(x)-f_N(y)|=c_N-f_N(y)>c_N-\frac{c_1}{2}>\frac{c_1}{2}=\epsilon$.

Does it look good? I am not sure how to justify that $c_1<c_2<\cdots$.

Comment: Since the functions $P_n(x):=(1-x^2)^n$ are non-negative and pointwise non-increasing on $[-1,1]$, their integrals are non-increasing, and the reciprocals of their integrals, $c_n$, are non-decreasing. Since the functions are continuous and $P_n(1/2)$ is strictly decreasing, these inequalities are strict. 

How do you justify that $Q_n\to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,-\delta/2]\cup [\delta/2,1]$?

Comment: @user469053 Uniform convergence is already justified in the textbook.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you wrote $f_N$ a few times when you meant $Q_N$, and it looks like you wrote $|f_N(\color{red}{x})-f_N(y)|$ in the last line when you meant $|Q_N(\color{red}{0})-Q_n(y)|$. 

Using $(1-x^2)^n\leqslant (1-x^2)$ on $[-1,1]$, we have $$c_n=\Bigl(\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^ndx\Bigr)^{-1} \geqslant \Bigl(\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)dx\Bigr)^{-1}=c_1,$$ and it looks good.

Comment: @user469053 Oops, you are right that $f_N$ should be $Q_N$. Actually, I defined $x=0$ in the first place. Thanks for checking over the proof!

Comment: Oops! Missed the $x=0$.